# How can I add a hyperlink to a ClutterText actor?

Tags: hyperlink, clutter

I've got a ClutterText object that I'd like to make display a clickable hyperlink. ClutterText has the option to use Pango markup but apparently not a way to mark a hyperlink.

Is there an easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the MeeGo Netbook user experience had a ClutterText sub-class that allowed highlighting and clicking URLs:

https://github.com/meego-netbook-ux/meego-panel-myzone/blob/master/penge/penge-clickable-label.c

the basics are:

- detect the boundaries of the URL inside the text (using a regular expression, generally);
- use PangoAttributes to change the style (underline + color);
- use the button-release-event signal, or the captured-event one if you want to allow other behaviours, to detect where the user has clicked inside the PangoLayout of the ClutterText;
- if the coordinates of the button event are within the boundaries of the link then success: emit a signal or call a function to handle the URL.

remember to make the ClutterText actor reactive if you want it to handle events. :-)